# Sending data with href in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I generate a lot of data in my controller `products`

I have a link like the following on the `products page`

```
<td><a href="/#/getProducts/{{name}}/status" {{ ProductName }}</a></td>
```

my data is calculated in the `products controller`

```
$scope.data = myData
```

Now instead of re-calculating everything from scratch on the `status page` and `status controller` I want to pass `myData` to the `status controller`

I also don't want to show the data in the URL

I'm not able to do so. any hints/resources are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you want to share same `mydata` of one controller onto another, then I would store that as part of service like `currentObject`.

So each time the user visits the controller that object will be overriden by new myData object.

In the other controller, I would just refer that object. This will make it easier without appending the data as part of the URL params.

Example:

In your service,

```
app.factory("ProductsService", function() {
   var service = {};
   // your properties for fetching etc
   var _myData;
   service.setMyData = function(myData) {
      _myData = myData;
   }

   service.getMyData = function() {
      return _myData;
   }
   return service;
});
```

In your one controller, before navigating set that object using `ProductService.setMyData(mydata)` and in another controller get it using `ProductService.getMyData()`

Answer (score 0):

use `localstorage` to set and get mydata value in different controller

```
window.localStorage.set("myData", JSON.stringify(myData));

var myData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.get("myData"));
```

Comment: I get undefined whenever I use localStorage ... must not supported maybe